# Fix delay on Push Notification Android usign Google Cloud Messagind GCM

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, slim

**There is a method to avoid delays when a push notification is received in android** ; I read about `com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT` and  `com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT`  but prior to implementation; I wonder if anyone knows about a method to correct the delay in the `GCM` notifications on Android. Currently called the push implement in `PHP` using Slim Framework.

Comment: Current implementation of GCM is perfect on most scenarios until you need very precise time and use of GCM PN. Heartbeat implementation does not reduce delay time but reduce Google to Device connection time. If you intent is very precise, use PULL mechanism instead of PUSH

Comment: PULL mechanism instead of PUSH ? you can give me explain precisely this mechanism? Thanks.

Comment: PULL is another way of calling polling mechanism, where  you call micro service every x interval.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about this method; I use High Priority in the fields of response.